# Regular Expression with dot or not all

Tags: regex, class

What is the regular expression for 4 and once or not at all 4.5?

```
if(pattern.matches) {

do something 

}
```

I have something like this: [2-5]?(\.[5]), but unfortunately does not work, I don't know why.

My example:

```
public static void userMarkBiology(){
do{
        System.out.print("Give Your mark from Biology");
    Pattern myPatterns=Pattern.compile("[2-5]+(\\.[5])");
    String mark=getUserThema();
if(myPatterns.matcher(mark).matches()){
    try{
        claasA.setUserMarkBiology(Double.valueOf(mark));
    }
    catch(PatternSyntaxException pse){
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("Error, You have to use marks like, 4 lub 4.5");
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("Something is wrong!");

}
while(SystemyOceny.getKomunikacjaSpolecznaWyklad() ==null);
```

Let's say in school student can get 4 or 4.5 and my program should accept both versions marks. Unfortunately accept only first or the second version, not both.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You should rephrase it and add some clear examples of what you expect should work and should not work. Please also add a language tag.

Comment: Add on your question examples of what should match and what shouldn't match. It will be easier for us to understand what you want.

Comment: You need `[2-5](?:\\.5)?`

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression [2-5]?(.[5]) matches only "4.5", not "4".

You have to postpone "?" to express and once or not at all the .5

The regular expression to match 4 and 4.5 is

```
[2-5](\.[5])?
```

in Java you have to double backslash:

```
"[2-5](\\.[5])?"
```

PS. try http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: I've edited your post to properly format your suggestion as a code. You just need to add a tab character or 4 spaces before of the code to make it look as code.

Comment: Thank for Your help!